# Cutting a specific part from a sentence, alternative solution need

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to combine below lines into one statement. I tried to do so by combining parameter expansion and command expansion but bash gave bad substitution error. As far as I see it is not possible to do nested expansions in bash. Can I do the same thing with regular expressions? I would appreciate any suggestion to do the same thing with another way in one statement.

```
rtm=$(unzip -p any.zip VENDOR/build.prop | grep "ro.vendor.build.id")
rtm=${rtm#*=}
```

Here I try to cut rtm info from a sentence. The sentence inside in VENDOR/build.prop. The sentence example: "ro.vendor.build.id=RTM.15482". In the end when I echo rtm I will see RTM.15482.

Comment: I did not actually mean it. You only suggest writing them into one line but in reality they are still two different operations in two lines. @knittl

Comment: You could append `| sed 's/[^=]*=//'` to the command pipe, replacing the entire second line, but characterwise, it wouldn't be any shorter.

Comment: Is "blabla" == "ro.vendor.build.id"?

Comment: @Sev the question is asking for a single "line", not for a single statement

Comment: @knittl yes you are grammatically correct. I will edit that part as statement but you actually could understand what I meant. I can easily think to write them into same line. And yes bllabla part also contains ro.vendor.build.id. It's a long sentence that contains my search key.

Comment: Aside: you should almost certainly be using `grep -F` or `grep -Fx` or `grep -Fw` or escaping the `.`s and adding anchors or something other than `grep "ro.vendor.build.id"` as that's doing a partial regexp match when you probably want a full line or full word string match. You may even need awk instead of grep if you need to focus on a field rather than a word or line.

Comment: [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input (a few lines of the output of `unzip -p any.zip VENDOR/build.prop` and the expected output (final content of `rtm`) given that input so we can help you as there's too many possibilities for what you might need with that and so it'd be easy for you to end up with the wrong solution that'll work for your current data values and then fail 6 months later on some real data.

Comment: `blabla=RTM.15482` wouldn't match `grep "ro.vendor.build.id"` so it tells us nothing about the kind of match you need and `blabla` tells us nothing about what values might be left of the `=` sign so that's not realistic or useful sample input. Show us some realistic sample input including rainy day cases like the strings you want to find being substrings of other strings you do not want to match, etc, It's always easy to match the strings you want (`.*` will match any string) but harder to not match similar strings you do not want.

Comment: I see your question was closed as a duplicate of your subject line but your subject line describes the solution you think you need to your problem when in fact you need a different solution. The easiest thing for you to do at this point to get a solution would be ask a new question but make your subject line about what you want to do (`print text after an "=" sign after matching a string`? It's not clear to me yet what you actually need) rather than how you want to do it and provide a [mcve] that really demonstrates your needs this time.

Comment: @EdMorton I did not provided what exactly inside the zip files because it does not matter. You can easily understand that I have a zip named any.zip and I am trying to unzip only the given single file VENDOR/build.prop to the console. My question is about parameter expansion and command expansion. So why do I need to explain the parts I do not need any help? It wouldn't help you to understand the question any better.

Comment: _sits here on team "you need to pick a better tool than grep; your actual needs have nothing to do with parameter expansions at all"_

Comment: All you guys trying to do on this platform to treat people as they are moron instead of trying to help. Some things are just obvious but you still come here and comment people saying that they are not clear enough. Next time I would explain even 2+2=4. To be crystal clear.

Comment: ...f/e, perhaps what you need is `rtm=$(unzip ... | awk -F= '$1 == "ro.vendor.build.id" { print $2 }')` -- no parameter expansions _at all_ in that statement.

Comment: but that's a "perhaps" because we don't have real sample data and real desired output, so we can't objectively test whether our answers are correct. **Yes**, we expect you to be crystal clear in providing a [mre] that reflects _exactly_ what you need when you're asking a question (and only to ask about what you _actually need_, vs what you _think_ someone might use towards getting you what you need -- doing the latter is how you get your question closed with a duplicate that covers what you asked for but not what you need).

Comment: @Sev we're trying to help you. You've asked how to do something that a) you don't need to do and b) is building on existing code that will almost certainly fail given some input values. We can see that adding parameter expansions is not the right solution to any problem you might have given what you've told us so far, but without knowing more about what you're trying to do there are many possible solutions for the many different problems you might have and so we can't help you get to the right solution yet and that's why we're asking for more information, not to make you feel like a moron.

Comment: One person has attempted to answer your question given what you've told us so far and you commented [Thanks but your solution did not work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77410117/combining-two-different-parameter-expansions-in-bash?noredirect=1#comment136469924_77410146). That alone should be enough evidence that we need more information in order to help you rather than that we're asking for it because we're trying to make you feel bad.

Comment: @pmf your suggestion works too. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Singe line:

```
rtm=$(unzip -p any.zip VENDOR/build.prop | grep -F 'ro.vendor.build.id'); rtm=${rtm#*=}
```

Without parameter expansion, but transforming output in the command substitution:

```
rtm=$(unzip -p any.zip VENDOR/build.prop | grep -F 'ro.vendor.build.id' | cut -d= -f2-)
```

Or using awk instead of grep + cut:

```
rtm=$(unzip -p any.zip VENDOR/build.prop | awk -F= '$0 ~ "ro\.vendor\.build\.id" { print $2 }')
```

If you need to match the first field exactly and there is only a single equal sign in each line, then the awk solution can be simplified even further:

```
rtm=$(unzip -p any.zip VENDOR/build.prop | awk -F= '$1 == "ro.vendor.build.id" { print $2 }')
```

Comment: You might want to add a note that the `awk` solution would break in the (maybe unlikely) situation of the prop value containing another `=` sign.

Comment: I doubt if any of those are a robust solution for the OPs real needs.

Comment: Thanks but your solution did not work for me. I tried cut version but it did not worked.

Comment: @Sev can you provide sample input which does not work? What does "it does not work" mean?

Comment: @Sev if the commands from your question worked, then the `cut` solution will work too

Comment: @knittl I'am sorry it's my mistake I forgot to go to the correct directory before running our code. Yes your solution with cut works. Thank you.

Comment: @knittl Can you explain what does -f2- part exactly do?

Comment: @Sev [`man cut`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html): `-f2-` selects fields 2 and all following.

Comment: @knittl what is field 2 in ro.vendor.build.id=RTM.15482? I couldn't understand it well. Before "=" sign is field 1 and anything after "="  sign is field 2 and rest? is "R" as a single char field 2 or is "RTM" field 2?

Comment: @Sev with delimiter "=", field 1 is "ro.vendor.build.id", field 2 is "RTM.15482", and all other fields are empty. It makes a difference if a line contains multiple delimiters

Comment: @knittl Okay thank you.

Comment: @Sev that's why it's so important to include the expected input in your question, even if it might be clear to you. You can see your input, we can't. Given proper input, the Stack Overflow community can suggest much better solutions to your problems.